# How to use request/session attribute after jquery ajax request?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, request, el

I have a form (comform) sent with this jquery ajax methode :

```
$(document).ready(OnReady);
function OnReady(){
   $('#comform').submit(onComm);
}
function onComm(data){
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr("method"),
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: newComment('${cid}')
    });
    return false;
}
```

Inside the servlet's code I do this :

```
request.setAttribute("cid", methode());
```

(for short, the servlet use the form inputs' values to fill a table in my DB then I retrieve the id of this insert, put it as attribute as shown above and that's it !)

But even if I set 'cid' in the session scope, I give an empty string to 'newComment' instead of the int that 'methode()' actually return.. In fact, the ${cid} element in not refresh..

What can I do to get this attribute without reload the page ?
How can I use some result datas ?
Thanks

Comment: `${cid}` will only be replaced with a value if the javascript is returned from the server.

Comment: If the script containing the javascript above is linked instead of being directly inside a `jsp`, the EL processor won't be able to replace the value. Your browser will be retrieving it verbatim.

Comment: the script is in the `<head>` of my jsp and if I reload the page as the 'cid' is in the session, `${cid}` is filled correctly !

Comment: Correct, because that's a round trip to the server. If you use ajax on the other hand, the javascript isn't changed, and therefore wherever you used `${cid}` also isn't changed.

Comment: So how can I get it without refresh ? Maybe in an other way ?

Comment: Ok, I find a way to do this with `response.getWriter().write(-cidvalue-)` but -cidvalue- is a string that `alert()` can show me but when i try to use it as html attribute like an "id" it change to `[object] [object]`... any suggestion ?